# CiviVoluteer sign up on WordPress embeds into The Events Calendar page

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

When on my WordPress site a non-logged user is signing up for a volunteer opportunity using CiviVolunteer firstly everything is OK ([the volunteer opportunities dashboard](https://esperanto.wiki/civicrm/vol#/volunteer/opportunities) is shown as expected). But after election of some opportunity and the first confirmation using the "SIGN UP!" button, the user is send to the second CiviVolunteer screen with profiles (what is expected), but that screen is embedded into [the specific (every time the same) event page](https://esperanto.wiki/evento/vikipediaj-pagoj-volas-fotojn-2021?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fvolunteer%2Fsignup&reset=1&needs%5B%5D=117&dest=list) created by the WordPress plug-in [The Events Calendar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/) - even the URL is that of the event (with CiviCRM parameters).

Volunteer sign up works - they are correctly recorded in CiviCRM and an email notification is correctly send. But the user experience is stranger, as the event page provides UI smog and is confusing.

Volunteer sign up for a logged-in user works well, in the expected page with expected URL.

After deactivating the WordPress plugin The Events Calendar, the CiviVolunteer dashboard stopped showing entirely for non-logged-in users, but works fine for logged-in.

For long time we have been using CiviCRM 5.36.0 and I do not recall this specific issue (but similar issue yes - with WordPress plugin [Popup Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-builder/), but that's for other question).

- WordPress 5.7.2
- CiviCRM 5.52.0
- CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1
- Angular Profiles 4.7.31-1.1.2
- The Events Calendar 5.16.4
- PHP (on web server) 7.4.30 (PHP on command line is different)

Comment: To clarify, you are on 5.52 or 5.36? Also is the civivolunteer profile embeded on a the events calendar page? Lastly - just a note, you should update your wordpress to atleast 5.9.2 for the latest security updates.

Comment: Currently our CiviCRM is 5.52.0. And it is in the problematic state described.

CiviVolunteer creates its own form on its own URL (which I can not change). We sometimes are using CiviCRM profiles on events pages, but not on the ones, that are problematic here, nor the profiles intended for CiviVolunteer.

Thanks about the WordPress note! We are working on it ;-)